# Payload Factory exception with invalid json

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

If I use a payload factory to create or simply to clean the payload in case of fault, the payload factory fail with an exception.
So, in case of error, I can't manipulate the payload.
I only need to remove it for example, so the fact that is invalid for me is not influential.

Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/DemoError" name="DemoError" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"status":"OK"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"status":"KO"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

In this example, if I made a call with an invalid json...
The ESB, it goes in the fault sequence (right) but when I try in the fault to clean the payload, the payload factory fail (org.apache.synapse.commons.SynapseCommonsException: Existing json payload is malformed), the worst thing is that failing the fault sequence it return http 202...very bad
I'm using WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your API. It is not failing actually. If I add a `<respond/>` mediator after Payload Factory mediator inside Fault Sequence, I can see that the Fault Sequence payload is returning correctly.

Comment: My example it's a simplification of a more complex project, I'll try the original again.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue, it's a little bit more complex.
If I have a validator, it goes in seems to go in the fault sequence, as expected, but now, the fault sequence fail on payload factory, returning http 202.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/DemoError" name="DemoError" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <validate cache-schema="true">
                <schema key="gov:custom/schema.json"/>
                <on-fail>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property name="ERROR" value="VALIDATE"/>
                    </log>
                </on-fail>
            </validate>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"status":"OK"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                        <property name="ERROR" value="I'M IN FAULT SEQUENCE"/>
                    </log>
            <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="500"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
"status":"KO"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

with the following schema:

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "example",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "input"],
  "properties": {
    "input": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "description": "Input"
    }
  }
}
```

and the following input:

```
{
    "input":xxx
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the issue reported in [1]. Until a GA release includes the fix, the WUM updated versions will contain the fix for the EI versions including wso2ei-6.6.0.

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2757